# Thunder Drake second spell of the turn

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I play [Thunder Drake](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bThunder%20Drake%5d) as my first spell of the turn, then cast another spell, will it get a +1/+1 counter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if Thunder Drake is the first spell you cast in a turn and then you cast another spell, that spell is the second spell you cast that turn, so Thunder Drake's ability triggers.

You're not supposed to think about it as though Thunder Drake is counting the spells, and only triggers on the second spell it sees you cast. Rather, it's simply a fact that whichever spell is the second one you cast that turn, independent of Thunder Drake.